# SELECT values from two different rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aggregate

I am working with a table that has

session_id : patient_id : efficiency_score

4871 : 32 : 99

4872 : 32 : 100

4872 : 32 : 50

My PHP code to select efficiency_score looks like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $efficiency_score[$c][$k] = $row['efficiency_score'];
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
```

and that's inside 2 for loops which explains the multidimensional array.

However, that code selects through every row in the table and I just want the maximum

```
efficiency_score
```

for each

```
session_id
```

How can I find the maximum efficiency_score and only have 1 efficiency_score per session_id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy. Use an aggregate query.

```
SELECT session_id, MAX(efficiency_score) AS efficiency_score
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY session_id
```

It's part of what SQL does beautifully and efficiently.  If you create a compound index on `(session_id, efficiency_score)` this query will be very fast indeed because MySQL can satisfy it using a [loose index scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html).

You can also use aggregate functions `MIN()`, `AVG()`, `STDDEV()`, `COUNT(*)`, and the like.

If you need to summarize a subset of the table you can specify a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT session_id, MAX(efficiency_score) AS efficiency_score
  FROM your_table
 WHERE session_id >= 1000  /* or whatever filter criteria */
 GROUP BY session_id
```

If you want to filter on aggregate results you can specify a HAVING clause, like this:

```
SELECT session_id, MAX(efficiency_score) AS efficiency_score
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY session_id
HAVING MAX(efficiency_score) <= 80   /*or whatever filter criterion*/
```

Comment: Thank you sir! And I guess this works for session_id's with just a single row as well?

Comment: Yes, it will work for any number of duplicate session_id values.

Comment: Would I just add the WHERE in the query before or after the GROUP BY or does it not matter?

Answer (score 1):

You're make it too hard on yourself. You can get the results from MySQL without the loops.

`SELECT session_id, MAX(efficiency_score) AS efficiency_score
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY session_id`